# How to get a type of an argument field in another argument type?

Tags: typescript

I want to know if there is a possibility to get a type of first argument in second argument type in a function. I have this code:

```ts
type Site = 'ABC' | 'XYZ';

type User = {
    email: string;
    sites: Site[];
};

const ADMIN: User = {
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    sites: ['ABC'] as const,
} as const;

function log(user: User, site: typeof user.sites[number]): void {
    console.log(`${user.email}/${site}`);
}

export function test(): void {
    log(ADMIN, 'ABC'); // This should compile - 'ABC' is in user ADMIN sites array
    log(ADMIN, 'XYZ'); // This should not compile - 'XYZ' is not in user ADMIN sites array
    log(ADMIN, 'GGG'); // This should not compile - 'GGG' is not in Site type
}
```

I would like to have a compile time check for the second argument of `log()` function. The only thing that I was able to do is `typeof user.sites[number]`. It checks if passed argument is included `Site` type. Additionally, I would like to check if this type is included in `ADMIN.sites`.

I will have a lot of `User` constants, and after passing the first argument, I would like to have hints and checks for the second argument. Second argument should only accept values from `sites` values from first argument.

Is there a way to do this in TypeScript?

Comment: That's [already an error](https://tsplay.dev/w6qP6W). But I guess you wanted something like `function log<U extends User>(user: U, site: U["sites"][number]): void {`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8qEEN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It looks like that is exactly what I wanted. I was not familiar with `satisfies` keyword. You can add it as an answer. A little explanation would also be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code that prevent this from working that way you want. In order for `log()` to care about the particular value being passed in as the `user` parameter, you have to make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that type.  Like this, for example:

```
function log<T extends User>(user: T, site: T["sites"][number]): void {
    console.log(`${user.email}/${site}`);
}
```

Here `user` is of the generic type `T` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `User`.  The type of `site` is given the nested [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T["sites"][number]`, to represent that it will have the same type as the element type of the `sites` array property of `user`, whatever that happens to be.  Conceptually it's the same as `typeof user.sites[number]`, but writing it like that causes the compiler to widen `user.sites` from `T["sites"]` to just `Site[]`, which defeats the purpose (see [microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181)).

Anyway this version will only let you pass in a `site` that's appropriate to the type of `user`.  But by itself this doesn't fix your problem:

```
const ADMIN: User = {
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    sites: ['ABC'] as const,
} as const;

export function test(): void {
    log(ADMIN, 'ABC'); // okay
    log(ADMIN, 'XYZ'); // still no error!!
    log(ADMIN, 'GGG'); // error
}
```

---

That brings us to the second problem.  You [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `ADMIN`'s type as `User`.  This throws away any more specific information the compiler may have had from the initializing value.  The type of `ADMIN` is just `User`, and thus its `sites` property is of type `Site[]`.

The [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) are completely useless. All it does is add some more information before you throw it away.

Instead of annotating, you really want to just say that `ADMIN`'s type should be *assignable* to `User` without widening it to that type.  That's the job of [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const ADMIN = {
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    sites: ['ABC'],
} satisfies User;

/* const ADMIN: {
    email: string;
    sites: "ABC"[];
} */
```

Here you've asked the compiler to interpret the object initializer in the context of the `User` type.  That causes it to infer `ADMIN`'s type as `{email: string; sites: "ABC"[]}`.  It's narrower than `User` in exactly the way you want it to be.  Note that I removed your `const` assertions because they're not necessary for your code to work.  You could, if you want, leave them in place.  It will have some effect on the type `ADMIN` (a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) for `sites` or making properties [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties)). But not anything that makes or breaks your example.

---

Let's test it:

```
export function test(): void {
    log(ADMIN, 'ABC'); // okay
    log(ADMIN, 'XYZ'); // error
    log(ADMIN, 'GGG'); // error
}
```

Looks good.  Now `ADMIN` knows that its `sites` property only has `"ABC"` elements, and `log()` knows that it should only allow the second argument to be assignable to the `sites` property elements of its first argument. And everything works as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglsaBeKByAggIQMKqgHzQA0BNALVQG4Aoa0SKAVQGcIAnKFAb2qj6ggBbAIZwANgC4ozYGzgA7AOY1+0hBGZT4iANoBdGgF8a1AMYB7eTKjoAIgFkAkgDlOUHqqGjJaYQBNBBQABRRFxADoLQVQAGl5+ZnVNKB0MHFQ9OMNpYWA4ZgAzOA0mVjYTAHoAKigLK2AbBxcpD34vcSkZOSUVBKSpACIsbAH9IygqitoCgFd5UzzLKDFzRQAeABUBAA9EeT9mUvYAPgAKGbKpDZi1RCudAcTEZgG9HXkZwQAjdj0ASikADdzHA-O54nw6sxzGIIOEVopTgADAAkXAu7HC7TEhgqaKeEEMSL+RloEG2YHMbAas3mi3kUGewFOAKgwNB4NUCNOdiczhuaVwJKgFQqUHMAGthCAIctVjymvziORUMLRQI2GwqbLubyXAKAOJG1WUEVi9hatjUQy0eTCQQaMDCUzQADy5jAh1akMs1j1zikLHYbm9qgEYR8qH8gXkIQjkXM0TiYb6zykqWGGSgwkOUOAyf42RztV9wBMngpVJpcwWcCWTJZQJBYNDXPl-oFmbVYsl0tlbcRHeVFG7UHk5g1lv7-F1isNxtHFu1qht1qAA)